# Get the post Author ID outside the WP Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

What I'm trying to accomplish is the code will auto detect the Author ID `<?php the_author_ID(); ?>` of the blogpost. Once it has the author ID, it will do a simple task. If the author # is equal to 2, call function sBadong. Else, if author ID is equal to 3, call function sJade. if two condition was not met, call function sBen.

here's my code, but it's not working. I dunno what wrong's with it. can you help?

```
<?php
$author_id=$post->post_author;
if ($author_id == "2") {
    echo sBadong();
} elseif ($author_id == "3") {
    echo sJade();
} else {
    echo sBen();
}
?>
```

The problem with the code above is it's not reading the Author Number of the post. It always returning the function sBen(); and ignore all if and else statements.

Comment: _but it's not working._ Can you explain that briefly ?

Comment: What's the error you have?

Answer (score 11):

Please use function as following:

```
$author_id = get_post_field ('post_author', $post_id);
```

It will work.

Comment: WHAT' S Faster get_post_field or get_post_meta, this used cache?

Comment: I think both are different get_post_field pulls data from wp_post table
while get_post_meta  fetches from wp_postmeta table